# Regular expression substitution with whitespace (perl)

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I would like to replace all matches of the following perl regular experssion

```
s@typedef\s*([\w\s<>,:]*)\s(\w+)\s*;@using \2= \1;@g
```

in a file.

I have done this with :

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e "s@typedef\s*([\w\s<>,:]*)\s(\w+)\s*;@using \2= \1;@g"  ./file.txt
```

The problem, the substituion does not work as long as I leave the whitespaces in "using \2= \1" ?   how can I make this work?

**ERROR: 
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.**

Comment: Try `'regex'` instead of `"regex"`.

Comment: Note that `s@...@...\1...@` makes no sense. `\1` means "match what what the first capture captured, which makes no sense outside of a regex. You want `$1`. Using `\1` currently warns.

Answer (score 0):

The shell in which you're invoking your perl command is doing substitution on the regular expression that you're passing in.

Use

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -i -e 's@typedef\s*([\w\s<>,:]*)\s(\w+)\s*;@using \2= \1;@g'  ./file.txt
```

instead.

The difference here is that the regex is in single quotes. This prevents shell substitution.

Comment: you migjht be right, thank you, it seems I haviong trouble calling bash functions with white space parameters!

Comment: Assuming that the only difference is to use single, rather than double quotes, perhaps it's worth explicitly stating that.